# Get All Users with Messages To/From Current User Sorted By Most Recent Event

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I have two Core Data entities, User and Message. One User entity is the "current user". I have a need to display a Messages screen that displays any communication between the current user and any other user. I'm using Core Data relationships here - a chat has ToUser and fromUser relationships, the inverse of which is chatsFrom and chatsTo.

I have a mostRecentMessageTimestamp transient property on the User entity, for sorting.

So in plain language, I want to get all Profiles that have communicated either to/from the current user, and then put the most recent ones on top. I'm staring at an NSPredicate trying to work out the syntax and failing - can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: A predicate chooses entities, but doesn't order them. Sorting is a separate operation.

Comment: I'm aware of that - I know I'll need to use NSSortDescriptor... somehow.